# How to record time of last activity in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails application I would like to record the time a `user` was `last_seen`.

Right now, I do this as follows in my `SessionsHelper`:

```
def sign_in(user)
  .....
  user.update_column(:last_seen, Time.zone.now)
  self.current_user = user
end
```

But this is not very precise because a user might log in at 8 a.m. and in the evening the `last_seen` database column will still contain that time.

So I was thinking to update `last_seen` whenever the user takes an action:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :update_last_seen

  private

  def update_last_seen
    current_user.last_seen = Time.zone.now
    current_user.save
  end
end
```

But I don't like that approach either because the database gets hit with every action that a user takes.

So what might be a better alternative to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails actually has this sort of behavior built in with `touch`:

```
User.last.touch
#=> User's updated_at is updated to the current time
```

The time it takes in any well-provisioned DB to handle updating a single column like this should be well under 5ms, and very likely under 1ms. Provided you're already going to be establishing that database connection (or, in Rails' case, using a previously established connection from a pool), the overhead is negligible.

---

To answer your question about whether your code is slower, well, you're thinking about this all wrong. You can optimize an already very fast operation for performance, but I instead you worry more about “rightness”. Here is the implementation of ActiveRecord's `touch` method:

```
def touch(name = nil)
  attributes = timestamp_attributes_for_update_in_model
  attributes << name if name

  unless attributes.empty?
    current_time = current_time_from_proper_timezone
    changes = {}

    attributes.each do |column|
      changes[column.to_s] = write_attribute(column.to_s, current_time)
    end

    changes[self.class.locking_column] = increment_lock if locking_enabled?

    @changed_attributes.except!(*changes.keys)
    primary_key = self.class.primary_key
    self.class.unscoped.update_all(changes, { primary_key => self[primary_key] }) == 1
  end
end
```

Now you tell me, which is *faster*? Which is *more correct*?

Here, I'll give you a hint: thousands of people have used this implementation of `touch` and this very code has likely been run millions of times. Your code has been used by you alone, probably doesn't even have a test written, and doesn't have any peer review.

“But just because someone else uses it doesn't make it empirically better,” you argue. You're right, of course, but again it's missing the point: while you could go on building your application and making something other humans (your users) could use and benefit from, you are spinning your wheels here wondering what is better for the machine even though a good solution has been arrived upon by others.

To put a nail in the coffin, yes, your code is slower. It executes callbacks, does dirty tracking, and saves all changed attributes to the database. `touch` bypasses much of this, focusing on doing exactly the work needed to persist timestamp updates to your models.

Comment: OK, nice. Didn't know that. But in the documentation it says that `touch` updates the `updated_at` field in the database. What if I want to update another field, say, the `last_seen` field? Will the code I posted above be any slower than the `touch` method? I assume that both methods will hit the database in some way.

Comment: @Tintin81 You should look a little closer at that documentation. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch

Comment: Ok, ok, you win ;-) I think you just made me fall in love with `touch`. Thanks for your help and the nice write up.